# Concatenating string with a dash in multiple choice

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to Concatenat string with leading dash in multiple choice to variable, but it doesn't work as expected and I don't know what is the problem

```
#!/bin/bash


filterOptionsStr=""
PS3='Filter Options: '
options=("Filter HTTP status codes from response"
    "skip/quit")
select option in "${options[@]}"; do
    case $option in
        "Filter HTTP status codes from response")
        
        echo $option
        read -ep "Status codes: " status_codes

        filterOptionsStr+=  "-fc ${status_codes} "
        echo $filterOptionsStr
        ;;    
        
        "skip/quit")
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

output:

```
└─$ ./test                                                                                                         130 ⨯
1) Filter HTTP status codes from response
2) skip/quit
Filter Options: 1
Filter HTTP status codes from response
Status codes: 301
./test: line 16: -fc 301: command not found

Filter Options: 1
Filter HTTP status codes from response
Status codes: 404
./test: line 16: -fc 404: command not found

Filter Options:
```

Comment: Remove the spaces between the `=` and the quote. When there's a space there, the shell is appending the empty string to the filterOptionsStr variable, and then attempting to execute "-fc $status_codes" **as a command**

Comment: Have a look at [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @glennjackman thank you so much

Comment: Also, please always check your script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) before posting. Thank you.

Comment: @thanasisp thank you, I didn't know about it